# Get the selected value of a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have the follwing code. I want to get the value of the selected value of the dropdownlist once the user changes it or to have the default value to be displayed by alert(). I need to use alert() from within the < body > of the html. Is that possible?

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Title</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js">
</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Util.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Language.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function dropdown(){
  var drp = document.getElementById("numberlist");
 var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
 optn.text="3";
 optn.value="3";
 drp.add(optn);
 }
    </script>
 </head>
  <body onload="dropdown();"> <div id="main3"></div>  <form><select id = "numberlist"><option>12</option><option>24</option><option>36</option></select>
```

> 

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: Thank Andy I tried that but when its used, it gives the default value of the dropdown list before selecting the required one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Following...Mark it as answer if it helps you

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Title</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"> </script> <script         type="text/javascript" src="JS/Util.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Language.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">    
function dropdown()
{   
    var drp = document.getElementById("numberlist");  
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");  
    optn.text="3";  
    optn.value="3";  
    drp.add(optn);  
}  

</script>  
</head>   
<body onload="dropdown();"> 
<div id="main3">
</div>  
<form>
<select id="numberlist" onchange="show()">
<option>12</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>36</option>
</select> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        var e = document.getElementById('numberlist');
        var txt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        alert(txt);


    }   
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the code:

```
selectElement.options[ selectElement.options.selectedIndex ];
```

to find the index that is selected.

So where you say `var drp = document.getElementById("numberlist");` you can now find the value of the index by doing:

```
var value = drp.options[ drp.options.selectedIndex ].value;
```

Add the code into an `onchange` event so that whenever you change the `selectedIndex` of the element, you will be able to obtain it's value:

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/axuwus/2/edit#preview)

Comment: David can you please tell me where I should use this.

Comment: Thanks David, I finally used user1484563's answer. +1 for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

add this function within script tag.

```
function pickvalue(id){
   var drp = document.getElementById(id);
   alert(drp.value);
}
```

and add function call like this.

```
<select id = "numberlist" onchange="pickvalue(this.id)">
```

Comment: Thanks Saifuddin.. I used user1484563's answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Saifuddin.  I've went straight to jQuery and am now tasked with editing some legacy scripts at work and need to learn plain jscript.  This was very helpful to get me rolling for an on change :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JQuery method:

```
 $value = $("#numberlist option:selected").text();
 alert($value);
```

Comment: Thanks Danny.. I used user1484563's answer. :)